# About redundant code when I use shortcode to output the HTML from a variable

Tags: shortcode, variables

I use shortcode to output the following html in a variable, but there are too many redundant code such as br and p tags, how to remove them? Thanks!

HTML MAKEUP

```
$return_html.='<div class="portfolio-item" id="portfolio-'.$post->ID.'"><a class="overlay'.$class.'" href="'.$url.'" title="'.$post->post_title.'"><h3>'.$post->post_title.'</h3><p class="intro">'.van_truncate($post->post_content,100).'</p></a><div class="tools"><a href="'.$url.'" class="zoomin'.$class.'" title="'.$post->post_title.'">ZoomIn</a><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" class="info">Info</a></div>
<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" class="item"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/pixel.gif" data-url="'.$thumbnail_url[0].'" class="scrollLoading" /></a></div>';
```

Current shortcode function

```
add_shortcode('portfolios', 'van_portfolios_shortcode');
function van_portfolios_shortcode( $atts, $content) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'number'=>'9',
        'slug'=>''
    ), $atts)); 
   $str=van_portfolios($slug,$number,false);
   return $str;
}

function van_process_shortcode($content) {
    global $shortcode_tags;
    // Backup current registered shortcodes and clear them all out
    $orig_shortcode_tags = $shortcode_tags;
    $shortcode_tags = array();
    add_shortcode('portfolios', 'van_portfolios_shortcode');

    // Do the shortcode (only the one above is registered)
    $content = do_shortcode($content);
    // Put the original shortcodes back
    $shortcode_tags = $orig_shortcode_tags;
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'van_process_shortcode', 7);
```

Correct makeup is

```
<div class="portfolio-item">
           <a class="overlay" href="#">
             <h3>...</h3>
             <p>...</p>
           </a>
           <div class="tools"><a href="#" class="zoomin" rel="lightbox">ZoomIn</a><a href="#" class="info">Info</a></div>
           <a href="#" class="item">...</a>
         </div>
```

Output:

```
<div class="portfolio-item">
           <a class="overlay" href="#">
             <br /><!--This <br />is redundant code-->
             <h3>...</h3>
             <p>...</p><p><!--This <p> is redundant code-->
           </a>
           <div class="tools"><a href="#" class="zoomin" rel="lightbox">ZoomIn</a><a href="#" class="info">Info</a></div>
           <p><!--This <p> is redundant code--><a href="#" class="item">...</a>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the content of a post - and therefore your shortcode - is run through the [`wpautop()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) function which generates the `<p>` and `<br />` tags in order to space out the post properly.

Shortcodes are run at priority 11, which is after `wpautop()` on priority 10. We can change the piority that this shortcode is run before `wpautop()`:

```
// This will do nothing but will allow the shortcode to be stripped
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'shortcode_foobar' );

// Actual processing of the shortcode happens here
function foobar_run_shortcode( $content ) {
    global $shortcode_tags;

    // Backup current registered shortcodes and clear them all out
    $orig_shortcode_tags = $shortcode_tags;
    remove_all_shortcodes();

    add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'shortcode_foobar' );

    // Do the shortcode (only the one above is registered)
    $content = do_shortcode( $content );

    // Put the original shortcodes back
    $shortcode_tags = $orig_shortcode_tags;

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'foobar_run_shortcode', 7 );
```

Code thanks to [@Viper007Bond](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/107/viper007bond) <sup>[[source](http://www.viper007bond.com/2009/11/22/wordpress-code-earlier-shortcodes/)]</sup>. Remember to replace the function and filter names with ones relating to your shortcode!

Comment: Thank you so much.I have corrected as your method and my codes is above, but it still generates the P and BR.